# Container of 3-item tuples with subscript operator-like capability for every item

Tags: c++, tuples

I have the following problem:

In one place of some legacy code is list of IDs of radio buttons. In another place is an array of corresponding strings. In yet another place is enum with corresponding values. Is there any clever way to combine all three values to have something like this pseudo code:

```
corresponding_enum1 = Container.IDs[id1].enum_value
corresponding_string1 = Container.IDs[id1].string_value

corresponding_id2 = Container.Enums[enum].id_value
corresponding_string2 = Container.Enums[enum].string_value
```

All I have come up with so far is this:

```
std::string my_strings[] = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" };
const int my_array[3][10] = 
{
    {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, // indexes
    {108, 106, 167, 123, 111, 168, 136, 104, 126, 194}, // enums
    {291, 275, 265, 201, 293, 244, 200, 248, 234, 285} // IDs
};

std::map<int, std::pair<int, int>> mapIndex;
std::map<int, std::pair<int, int>> mapEnum;
std::map<int, std::pair<int, int>> mapID;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    mapIndex[my_array[0][i]] = std::make_pair(my_array[1][i], my_array[2][i]);
    mapEnum[my_array[1][i]] = std::make_pair(my_array[0][i], my_array[2][i]);
    mapID[my_array[2][i]] = std::make_pair(my_array[0][i], my_array[1][i]);
}

int query = 244;
std::cout << "Id = " << query << "\t Index = " << mapID[query].first << "\t Enum" << mapID[query].second << "\n";
```

but I think it is better way to do this. Any advice?

Comment: No time for a full fledged answer but I have used (and seen that others "invented" something like that as well) defines for that. The idea is that you have exactly one place where you link names, IDs and values in the shape `MY_MACRO(ZERO, 108, 291)` , each line describing one item. Then you (re-)define that macro according to your needs in the code, i.e. to map assignments, complementary array element assignments etc. (also with the help of the stringize operator so that enums and strings are created from the same character sequence) in MY_MACRO before including the same file each time.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Could you give me an example how to retrieve enum and index from id 293 according to your method?

Answer (score 0):

What I do here is not so far from your own code, it just bundles information about
all items (radio buttons) nicely with less chance of wrong placements (it's clear which 
butto ID connects to which enum). Adding or removing a button is done with a change only in a
single place, the macro text file. The sources are not affected. If the information is extracted from some documentation (I used this technique in order to write a PCL6 parser, mapping tokens to paper names like "A4" to paper dimensions and such) there is a chance that the text file can be produced (semi-) automatically. Btw, I assume that the "index" may not be contiguous for later items or it could be omitted because the "enoms" would automatically be the index sequence.

Edit: Re-reading your question I notice that you speak of legacy code. My solution obviously depends on you being able to change that code (i.e. change the array definitions in your example to the format in macro-enums.txt).

macro-enums.txt:

```
//       name, index, enum, id
MY_MACRO(zero,  0,   108,   291)
MY_MACRO(one,   1,   106,   167)
MY_MACRO(two,   2,   167,   265)
```

macro-enums.cpp:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<int, int> idMap;    // index -> id
    map<int, int> enumMap;  // index -> enum 
    map<int, const char *> nameMap;  // index -> "name" 
    map<const char *, int> indexMap; // "name" -> index
    // possibly other mappings

    // First let's define symbolic constants one, two etc. 
    // for the indexes. The last enum element will have a trailing
    // comma which is allowed in order to 
    // simplify exactly this kind of code generation.
#   define MY_MACRO(name, index, enom, id) name = index,
    enum indexEnumE 
    {
#       include "macro-enums.txt"   
    };

#   undef MY_MACRO

    // an enum with names like id_of_one 
    // with the corresponding id as value. 
    // Similarily doable for other
    // attributes of a button as needed. Uses the 
    // preprocessor concatenation operator ##.
#   define MY_MACRO(name, index, enom, id) id_of_##name = id,
    enum idEnumE 
    {
#       include "macro-enums.txt"   
    };

#   undef MY_MACRO

    // now let's define a map index -> id, index -> enum, 
    // index -> "name" and "name"->index
#   define MY_MACRO(name, index, enom, id) \
    idMap[index] = id; \
    enumMap[index] = enom; \
    nameMap[index] = #name; \
    indexMap[#name] = index;
    // possibly other mappings

#   include "macro-enums.txt"   

#   undef MY_MACRO

    /////////// example use /////////////
    int ind = 2;
    cout << "The enum of index " << ind << " is "
        << enumMap[ind] << endl;

    const char *name = "one";

    cout << "The index of name \"" << name << "\" is "
        << indexMap[name] << endl;

    if( idMap[zero] == id_of_zero ) 
    {
        cout << "The id enum of \"" <<  nameMap[zero]
            << "\" is as expected " << id_of_zero << endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "Internal error: The id enum of \"" << nameMap[zero] 
            << "\" unexpectedly is " << id_of_zero 
            << " but should be " << idMap[zero] << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

`$ ./macro-enums
The enum of index 2 is 167
The index of name "one" is 1
The id enum of "zero" is as expected 291`

Comment: By legacy code in this case I mean that I can't change enum and ID values because many files depend on them. Changing these values and making them consecutive will ease everything.

Thanks for the answear and for the time spent on answearing!

Comment: Then you could use this technique. In new code you can use the symbolic enums zero, one etc. instead of literals for better style. It is btw also possible to define symbolic enums like id_one, id_two etc for the IDs. I'm editing to include an example.